# Getting contact displayName and phoneNumbers

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic contacts native for getting the list of contacts from phone

.ts:

```
 import { Contacts } from 'ionic-native';
   /////////
 export class ContactPage {
   contactsfound = []

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    Contacts.find(["displayName", "phoneNumbers"], {multiple: true}).then((contacts) => {
     this.contactsfound = contacts;
    })
   }
 }
```

.html:

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
   <ion-list-header>Follow us on Twitter</ion-list-header>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of contactsfound">
       {{ item.displayName }}
       <p>{{ item.phoneNumbers }}</p> 
     </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

I am getting the list of `displayName` correctly however for `phoneNumbers` i get `[object Object]` 
How to do this??
Also, I want to have a letter on the left-side of the list where is represents the first letter of a group of contacts starting with that letter (e.g. A list group then scrolling B list group) .... it would be great if someone provides an insight regarding this. thanx

Comment: Try to print the object in console and debug: `console.log(JSON.stringify(contactsfound))`. phoneNumbers property is clearly an object and not a number/string value

Comment: @suraj ... I can't print in console, this plugin only works on real device...and yes its an object whereas displayName is string... it seems that `phoneNumbers` is an array of all contacts phone numbers... so how to access them and display them accordingly

Comment: you can still see console logs using chrome developer tools.. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: if ios then safari web inspector

Comment: When I open the page in console , it throws an error `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`... but this is not the case when I run the app on real device

Comment: You need to wrap plugin calls in platform.ready().then(()=>//call plugin)

Comment: Try to log the true value of the phoneNumbers object to the screen like this: `<p>{{ item.phoneNumbers | json}}</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem as follows:

.ts:

```
import { Contacts } from 'ionic-native';
 /////////
export class ContactPage {
 contacts = []
 groupedContacts = []

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
   Contacts.find(["displayName", "phoneNumbers"], {multiple: true, hasPhoneNumber: true}).then((contacts) => {

    for (var i=0 ; i < contacts.length; i++){
     if(contacts[i].displayName !== null){
       var obj = {};
       obj["name"] = contacts[i].displayName;
       obj["number"] = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value;
       this.contacts.push(obj)    // adding in separate array with keys: name, number
     }      
    }

    this.groupContacts(this.contacts);
  })
}

groupContacts(contacts){

  let sortedContacts = contacts.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
   });

  let currentLetter = false;
  let currentContacts = [];

  sortedContacts.forEach((value, index) => {
    if(value.name.charAt(0) != currentLetter){
      currentLetter = value.name.charAt(0);

      let newGroup ={
        letter: currentLetter,
        contacts:[]
      };

      currentContacts = newGroup.contacts;
      this.groupedContacts.push(newGroup);
    }
    currentContacts.push(value);
  });
}
```

.html:

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">
    <ion-item-divider color="light">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts" class="contactlist">
       {{contact.name}}
       <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
     </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

Comment: The above solution is not working with the latest ionic-native contacts plugin can someone help me  out pls.

Comment: I haven't been using ionic lately, I hope someone can update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem when displaying searched contacts with numbers in a list. Try to edit your first post with this.

.html

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of contactsfound">
   {{ item.displayName }}
   <p>{{ item.phoneNumber[0].value }}</p> 
 </ion-item>
```

Apparently, this method only shows one number of each contact. For multiple numbers, just add another item.phoneNumber[1].value and so forth.